# Using Google Map API to access near by school

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I access or show Schools/Place of interst near by area (lat/long) using Google Map API

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do that with the google map api.  You can try the [google places api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearchRequests) using a place search request.